# granting file permissions in python 2.6

Tags: python, filesystems

I'm writing this basic code , now i want to give 777 to ctp directory.. what is the best way to do that

```
import os
import sys

print ("Checking all required directories first...")

def checkDir():
    x='/home/aspx/psharma1'
    if os.path.isdir('x/tmp/ctp'):
        print("Directory /x/tmp/ctp exists..")
    else:
        os.mkdirs("/x/tmp/ctp")
```

Comment: `enter code here` is a formatting error. pls ignore that

Comment: `os.chmod("/x/tmp/ctp",0o777)` maybe python 2.6 needs old-style octal `os.chmod("/x/tmp/ctp",0777)`

Comment: thanks... but was is 0o before 777 meant for?

Comment: octal prefix, required in python 3, maybe not available yet in python 2.6. Use `0777` that will work (but not portable in python 3)